Gemini AI Feature Stopped Working in Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Canary 5
I am using Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Canary 5 on a Mac. The Gemini AI feature suddenly stopped working across all my projects. Here are the steps I've already tried:


Invalidate Caches and Restart in Android Studio

Restarted my system

Reinstall Android Studio



Unfortunately, neither of these steps resolved the issue. I understand that the Canary build of Android Studio may have stability issues, but I am wondering if this could be a configuration problem within Android Studio itself.
The last command I entered in Gemini was /exit.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to fix it? Any help would be highly appreciated.


Where did you post it?

By stopped working, do you mean that you can't log back in?

I switched from Android Studio to Koala 2024.1.1 stable because I needed an IDE urgently. Since then, I have not faced any issues with Gemini AI.
